# how to parse json object using jquery and print the output in tabular format in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have written a program to create a json object from the list of values obtained from database and here is how my json looks

```
{
 1: {
 age: "21",
 name: "arjun",
 gender: "male"
},
 2: {
 age: "30",
 name: "ravi",
 gender: "male"
},
 3: {
 age: "57",
 name: "pushpa",
 gender: "female"
 }
}
```

Now i want to parse it using jquery and print the result in tabular form in html.
I have tried to some extent , but not understanding what to do further, so please need some guidance

My json_parse.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = "http://182.168.1.115:8082/JqueryForm/userdetails_json.jsp"
$.parseJSON(url, function(json) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].age + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].gender + "</td>");
        $("#table").append(tr);
    }
});
```

});

My list_user.html:

```
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<script src="json_parse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table name="Table" id="table">

    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your output look like currently? Are you getting any rows at all in your table?

Comment: Is your json data well-formed? Try to call it directly from a browser address bar.

Comment: @Daryl just blank html page

Comment: @collapsar yes sir , i can see my json data very well in my brower

Comment: Are you receiving any console errors? I would set a break point inside your loop and make sure json is actually formatted the way you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you've got a couple problems:

1. You should be using [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) not [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)
2. You're JSON isn't an array, so length is not defined and you cannot loop through it the way you are.

The easy fix is to re-write your loop using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to enumerate your object:

```
$.each(json, function(i) {
  var tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].age + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].gender + "</td>");
  $("#table").append(tr);
});
```

There's a working snippet below to see it in action.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json = { 1: {age: "21", name: "arjun",gender: "male"}, 2: {age: "30",name: "ravi",gender: "male"}, 3: {age: "57", name: "pushpa", gender: "female"}};
  
  $.each(json, function(i) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].age + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].gender + "</td>");
    $("#table").append(tr);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: sir , i had used getJSON before, but i am not seeing any result on my browser when i run my html code

Comment: I found your other issue. Please see my updated answer